# is there a php method that display the deleted at items with deleted date in view?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to get the deleted items from database ,i used laravel soft deleting method and display it in view.

I had insert the soft deleting method on my model and schema migration .

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('contracts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
    }
```

The method works fine and the deleted_at shown on database ,now i want to display each deleted items in historic view .

Comment: Just read the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#soft-deleting), and there is no a **PHP method** for this.

Comment: why not try to use the other way. `Model::where('deleted_at', null)->get();`

Comment: @MONSTEEEER because there is a scope that does this and is named nicely https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/SoftDeletingScope.html

Comment: @Kyslik, Nice mate. Thankyou,

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your question can be found in the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#soft-deleting)

When in your controller you want to retrieve the deleted items, you have 2 scopes:

`withTrashed` and `onlyTrashed` that can be used to retrieve all the items from the database with the trashed elements or only the trashed elments.

For example, if you have inside your database 3 users (2 active and one deleted) this query will retrieve all items:

```
$users = Users::withTrashed()->all();
```

The result will be:

```
[
  ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'user1', ..., 'deleted_at' => null],
  ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'user1', ..., 'deleted_at' => 'Y-m-d HH:mm:ss'], 
  ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'user1', ..., 'deleted_at' => null], 
]
```

Otherwise, if you want only the trashed elements:

```
$users = Users::onlyTrashed()->all();
```

The result will be:

```
[
  ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'user1', ..., 'deleted_at' => 'Y-m-d HH:mm:ss'], 
]
```